# VS 2017 using c++ debugger for C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a problem with VS2017 on my machine. When I try to debug C# code it use the c++ debugger as you can see on the image below. Therefore I can't see all my variable etc. I tried to reinstall VS2017, uninstall - install, sfc /scannow but it doesn't work. I don't have any problem with VS2015.

[image: Exemple]